# Add VisualForce rendered as pdf as an attachement on a record

Tags: apex, email, pdf

I have a VisualForce rendered as a PDF, I want to add it as an attachement to my record once created. Any idea?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a simple method to save a pdf as an attachment - called from a trigger.

```
       @future
       public static void saveQuote(id objId){
               //create pagereference object and set to your VF page.
                PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/'+quotePage);
                pr.getParameters().put('id',objId);
                //get the content as a PDF
                Blob b = pr.getContentAsPDF();
                Attachment att = new Attachment();
                att.Body = b;

                        //set which record to save the pdf against.
                att.ParentId = objId;


                att.Name = 'My attachment.pdf';
                att.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
                insert att;


            }

}
```

Comment: Con in instance of contact do you mean?

Comment: I have a page that is using a standardController (con) and I'm just using this to get the id to pass to the VF page. Upto you what you need to pass to your custom page and where this data comes from. The main points are the pr.getContentAsPDF() and the attachment fields you need to populate. I then return to the view page of the record I had loaded via the standardController by the con.view()

Comment: It doesnt know my page, VFPDF variable doesnt exist!! 
`public pageReference AttCertificate() {
            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/'+VFPDF);
            pr.getParameters().put('id','User.Id');
            Blob b = pr.getContentAsPDF();
            Attachment att = new Attachment();
            att.Body = b;
            att.ParentId = Certificate__c.Id;
            att.Name = 'MyCertificate.pdf';
            att.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
            insert att;
            return Certificate__c.view();
}`

Comment: try PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VFPDF');

Comment: Yes right!! but this assignement is illigal `att.ParentId = Certificate__c.Id; ` Ceretificate__c is the standardController in my VisualForce Pag

Comment: You'll need to add a reference either to the standard Controller or to the record (in your case the certificate__c). I'll update my answer to show you

Comment: I have a problem with the trigger `trigger CertficateAfterInsert on Certificate__c (after insert) {
 
 if(!Trigger.New.isEmpty()){
  for (Certificate__c certif : Trigger.new){
   TRCertificateAttachement.AttCertificate();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Try making @future - see update

Comment: But the future annotation can only return a void type!!

Comment: Well, just remove the return statement. Have updated code...